# What does this green icon mean in a github repository?

Tags: git, github

What does this green icon mean in Github? I know the commit link takes me to another repository. I need to do something similar. Is this a symlink? Or a submodule? Being still somewhat new to git, I'm wondering how I can replicate this myself. Once created, how do I update this external dependency?

[image: Git repository - what's up with the green icon?]

Comment: Looks like a submodule to me.  What do you see in the `.gitmodules` file? What do you mean by 'update this external dependency'?

Comment: Yep, that's a submodule... more on them here: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: aha. i see: [submodule "page-js"] path = page-js url = https://github.com/visionmedia/page.js.git

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a submodule: a link to a specific commit in another repository at a different URL.  The repository will be cloned when `git submodule update --init` is run, and then the referenced commit (`784fd39`) will be checked out.

You can create submodules using `git submodule add <url> <directory>`, which will add a submodule reference for the given URL at the directory you specify, in the current working directory.

Comment: great thanks -- assuming the file gets updated with a different commit, how do I re-init the submodule to go at the latest commit? Or does running `git submodule update` once the `init` has already take place automatically link the submodule to the latest commit?

Comment: @TimDog No, that will update the checked-out clone to point to the commit referenced by the submodule.  To update the cloned repository to the latest commit, just `cd` into that repository and run `git pull --ff-only` like you usually would.  Then you will have to `git add` the changed submodule and `git commit` the result in order for this change to be committed to your outer repository.  (Which commit to check out in a submodule is as much a history of the repository as anything else.)

Comment: @TimDog I'd be surprised if that worked -- submodules cannot reference individual files, nor can they reference subdirectories.  You will receive an error when you `git submodule update --init` as that URL does not point to a repository at all.

Comment: thanks for the tips. I deleted my errant comment about the indiv file (because you were right, that didn't work). So there is no way to link to just a single file from a repo? (I realize that's a separate question altogether).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43601977/4652621).
It's from another question in  So, That topic is [What does a grey icon in remote GitHub mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19584255/what-does-a-grey-icon-in-remote-github-mean?noredirect=1&lq=1)
You can ignore submodule step which is very complex.

Comment: Can you please add some of the information from that article to your answer so it can be accepted to the SO community?