# Git FULL push , no refs?

Tags: git, vim, github, git-push, git-clone

I am trying to push my `.vim` directory to github.

I am using [pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) ,so under `.vim/bundle` , I have some plugins , which are git repos too.

when I push to github they are converted to green folder icons (which as I understand are a ref to other repos).

here is a screen shot.

[image]

I want a full Backup of my `.vim`, so I could do `git clone` to my other machines too.

- can I clone the repo from github full functional clone ? I get empty dirs under .vim/bundle.
- or push it **FULLY** from my local machine , and avoiding those green folders all together ?

Comment: Try `git rm --cached bundle`, `git add bundle/*/`.

Comment: first command deleted the files under bundle , second one added it again.So git status did not show any thing , should I commit and push again,  if possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git will detect git repositories in subdirectories, and add them as such by default – only noting the SHA of their currently checked out commit. You can circumvent that behaviour by running `git add subfolder/*`. But this only works if the given subfolder is not currently part of the cache. So in your case you need to run these commands (assuming there are no spaces in your folder names):

```
git rm --cached bundle
ls --color=never bundle | xargs -t -n1 -I {} git add "bundle/{}/"
```

Comment: Thank you !! I had to do it manually for every folder under bundle/ but it worked !! *note* that the xargs command did not work , here is the output fatal: pathspec 'bundle/{}/*' did not match any files.

Comment: I edited the answer and add the right format of xargs command.

Comment: Glad I could help, but I am confused – I tried that command before I posted it and it works for me. And I can’t see any edit?

Answer (score 0):

[What does this green icon mean in a github repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448601/what-does-this-green-icon-mean-in-a-github-repository)

Looks like submodule. Check for a file named .gitmodules at the source of your git.

If this file exists you need to clone the repository as following:

```
git clone address
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

Comment: Thank you. I dont have .gitmodules file under .git

Comment: Not under .git, but in the root of your git.

Comment: Oh ok , I have .git, .gitignore

Comment: Did ``git ls-files | grep vim-blade'' return some files? (or for any other repo?

Comment: Not on the cloned repo. Git couldn't commit empty directory.

Comment: I am doing this on my local repo no in a cloned one. Which is the repo I pushed to github with empty dirs.(As the screen shows above)

Comment: These are not empty dirs, but commits. Yes, a git directory tree can contain a commit as one of its entries – that’s part of how submodules work.