# Can't Push Commit a Folder from Egit?

Tags: git, egit, git-push, git-commit

I am having three Project folders in Eclipse.I want to push those folders into Git through EGit .

[image]

Only two folders are being Pushed .The Client is not being Pushed. I am followedthe same procedure for all the projects.

I don't know why it is show the client in a Different way ...

[image]

Thanks for your Help ..

Comment: That's why it makes sense to learn git command line interface first

Comment: Judging by the time of last update in the screenshot, it looks like the `Remote Client` folder was updated too along with the other two. Can you elaborate further?

Comment: Looks like a submodule. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19584255/what-does-a-grey-icon-in-remote-github-mean