# github/git: github not showing files in subdirectory

Tags: git, github

Created a new github repo, and added everything in a directory, and added to the repo. I noticed that the subdirectory is visible on github but grayed out - I can't click it. Doing a `git ls-files`, I see all the files added. I don't believe this directory's contents were ever sent to github because it's a large directory and the git push took almost no time at all.

Why can't I see this subdirectory on github?

Below shows the list from github.com. ".vim" subdirectory is grayed out.

[image]

EDIT:

I created a repo from one of the subdirectories a long time ago and forgot about it. The .git file in that subdirectory prevented me for adding it into the new repo. Resolution would be to link it as a submodule, or choose that directory to belong to either the new repo or old.

Going to keep this open as I came about this issue quite differently than the other linked SO question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does a grey icon in remote GitHub mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19584255/what-does-a-grey-icon-in-remote-github-mean)

Comment: Keeping it open because mine comes up with different search keywords. Gray vs grey and subdirectories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be **[submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)**, as [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19584255/6309).

When you clone that repo, you need to do a:

```
git submodule update --init
```

That will allow you to see the content of that folder.

Comment: You are right. I created a repo from one of the subdirectories a long time ago and forgot about it. The .git file in that subdirectory prevented me for adding it into the new repo. Resolution would be to link it as a submodule, or choose that directory to belong to either the new repo or old.

Comment: @imagineerThis indeed. Uou can remove the **[gitlink entry](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)**: `git rm --cached .vim` (no trailing slash), and add everything in your main repo (in order to make is part of the new repo).