# ! [rejected] master -> master (fetch first)

Tags: git, git-push

Is there a good way to explain how to resolve "`! [rejected]  master -> master (fetch first)'`" in Git?

When I use this command  `$ git push origin master` it display an error message.

```
! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:zapnaa/abcappp.git'
```

Comment: git push origin master --force

Comment: @Omarbakhsh NO to the above, you will wipe out commits you are missing potentially. It is absolutely unclear if this is the intention!

Answer (score 210, accepted):

The answer is there, git is telling you to fetch first.

Probably somebody else has pushed to master already, and your commit is behind. Therefore you have to fetch, merge the changeset, and then you'll be able to push again.

If you don't (or even worse, if you force it by using the `--force` option), you can mess up the commit history.

EDIT: I get into more detail about the last point, since a guy here just gave the Very Bad Advice of using the `--force` option.

As git is a DVCS, ideally many other developers are working on the same project as you, using the same repository (or a fork of it). If you overwrite forcefully with your changeset, your repository will mismatch other people's, because "you rewrote history". You will make other people unhappy and the repository will suffer. Probably a kitten in the world will cry, too.

TL;DR

1. If you want to solve, fetch first (and then merge).
2. If you want to hack, use the `--force` option.

You asked for the former, though. Go for 1) always, even if you will always use git by yourself, because it is a good practice.

Comment: @cantaş `fetch` alone doesn't change your code locally because it only gets the meta-data info about  the latest changes that were made from the remote repo. Basically it gives you the latest news about what happened since your last pull. If you want to bring the actual changes into your local repo you will then use `pull`. What `pull` does the same as `fetch` AND actually gets them.

Comment: fetch and merge accomplishes what pull does but allows them to review the changes first.

Answer (score 140):

try:

```
git fetch origin master
git merge origin master
```

After to wrote this code I received other error: (non-fast-forward)

I write this code:

```
git fetch origin master:tmp
git rebase tmp
git push origin HEAD:master
git branch -D tmp
```

And resolved my problem

Comment: Same for me. That solved my problem. There are a couple of warnings. I messed up with a sub repository, but solved it with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19584255/what-does-a-grey-icon-in-remote-github-mean

Comment: @Aurelio A   Your merge command is incorrect, it should be `git merge master`.

Comment: Why we need to use git branch -D tmp ?

Answer (score 42):

You should use  `git pull`, that´s command do a `git fetch` and next do the `git merge`.

If you use a `git push origin master --force` command, you may have problems in the future.

Comment: Is it correct that you should only use --force if you're the only one on the project and you're getting frustrated trying to do your first push?

Answer (score 37):

pull is always the right approach but one exception could be when you are trying to convert a none-Git file system to a Github repository. There you would have to force the first commit in.

```
git init
git add README.md
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/userName/repoName.git
git push --force origin master
```

Comment: works for me, I started again a new project (same repo) and I wanted to replace it.

Answer (score 27):

As it is stated in the Error message you have to "fetch first." This worked for me.
Use the command:

1. `git fetch origin master`

Then follow these steps to merge:

2. `git pull origin master`
3. `git add .`
4. `git commit -m 'your commit message'`
5. `git push origin master`

Answer (score 25):

Try this git command

```
git push origin master --force
```

or short of force `-f`

`git push origin master -f`

Comment: This overrides git push restriction. Not recommended for teamwork. From git push documentation: _If somebody else built on top of your original history while you are rebasing, the tip of the branch at the remote may advance with her commit, and blindly pushing with --force will_ **lose her work**.

Answer (score 9):

Follow the steps given below as I also had the same problem:

```
$ git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

(To see if local branch can be easily merged with remote one)

```
$ git push -u origin master
```

(Now push entire content of local git repository to your online repository)

Answer (score 5):

This happens when your teammate have already committed. so his commit is on top.
To avoid you do rebase (merge , fetch).

I solved my issue with the following.

1. `git pull --rebase origin master`
2. `git push -u origin master`

you can see logs `git log`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following command:
First clone a fresh copy of your repo, using the --mirror flag:

```
$ git clone --mirror git://example.com/some-big-repo.git
```

Then follow the codes accordingly:

[Adding an existing project to GitHub using the command line](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/)

Even if that doesn't work, you can simply code:

```
$ git push origin master --force
```

or

```
$ git push origin master -f
```

Answer (score 4):

Quickest solution-

1. DO a git log->
   You will see someone probably has pushed some code post the time you had pulled the latest codebase.
2. DO a git pull --rebase, this will first, rewind head to replay your work on top of it and then apply your committed changes to the same.
3. You are now all set for a git push.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "commit"
$ git push origin master --force
```

Answer (score 3):

! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)

in this error showing time if you first checking your folder place correct path. And type: -

git push origin master --force

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that someone else (e.g. your colleague) has put commits onto `origin/master` that aren't in your local `master` branch, and you are trying to push some commits from your local branch to the server. In 99% of cases, assuming you don't want to erase their work from `origin`, you have two options:

2) Merge their changes into your local branch, and then push the merged result. 
`git checkout master 
git pull  # resolve conflicts here 
git push`

(Note that `git pull` is essentially just a `git fetch` and a `git merge` in this case.)

1) Rebase your local branch, so that it looks like your colleague made their commits first, and then you made your commits. This keeps the commit history nice and linear - and avoids a "merge commit". However, if you have conflicts with your colleague's changes, you may have to resolve those conflicts for each of your commits (rather than just once) in the worst case. Essentially this is nicer for everyone else but more effort for you.

`git pull --rebase  # resolve conflicts here
git push`

(Note that `git pull --rebase` is essentially a `git fetch` and a `git rebase origin/master`.)

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it happens when you duplicate files typically README sort of.

Answer (score 2):

Your error might be because of the merge branch.
Just follow this:

step 1 : `git pull origin master` (in case if you get any message then ignore it)
step 2 : `git add .`
step 3 : `git commit -m 'your commit message'`
step 4 : `git push origin master`

Answer (score 2):

> I had faced this error while pressing the **git push** command.

- The problem solved by simply adding -*force* after *git push*
- **Solution:** *git push -fource*

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When we try to push the folder on Github using below-mentioned command

```
  $ git push origin master
```

and get the error like this:

```
To https://github.com/Raushan1156/QR-Code.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Raushan1156/QR-Code.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
```

Try this command to solve your issue, it's solved my error.

```
$ git push origin master --force
```

One Pic has been attached for a visual explanation.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

! [rejected]        main -> main (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Wasif-M/Micard-Flutter.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Use this command after that:

**git push -f origin main**

i hope error will remove and your repository will commit to gitHub

Answer (score 1):

I overcame this by checking-out a new branch like this :

```
# git checkout -b newbranch <SHA of master>

# git branch
* newbranch
  master

# git push -u <repo_url_alias> newbranch
```

You are left with 2 branch : Master and newbranch , that you can manage to merge later.

Answer (score 1):

It is happen when you create a repository in GitHub and select `README` or `.gitignore` or `license` files.
delete repasotory if it is empty and create it again without selecting `README` ,`.gitignore` or `license` files.

Answer (score 1):

to Solve it added a "--force"

**git push --force origin master**

or pull it first and pull
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**You just have to mention your branch name along with your remote name.**

```
git fetch origin
git merge origin/master
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it happened in my case was when creating the GitHub rep link, I initialized it with **README file**

While creating Git remote do not initialize it with README file otherwise it would show err

Don't do that & it will definitely work fine
Instead initialize it with the readme file if you wish to after pushing to the master branch

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, since none of the other solutions worked for me.
NOT EVEN FORCE!

https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/resolving-a-merge-conflict-using-the-command-line

Just had to go through Git Bash

```
cd REPOSITORY-NAME
git add .
git commit -m "Resolved merge conflict by incorporating both suggestions."
```

Then back to my cmd and I could: `git push heroku master` which in my case was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

*It is very easy to fix, run the following command:*

`git fetch origin master`

Answer (score 0):

If this is your first commit and you are trying to push local code to a new repository, you probably are getting this error because you added a README when you created the repo on github. Next time you create a new repo, do it WITHOUT adding a README on github.

Answer (score 0):

This solution helped me :

git init
git add README.md
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/userName/repoName.git
git push --force origin master