# While pushing to github, ! [rejected] master -> master (fetch first) error: failed to push some refs to "<github-link>"

Tags: git

When I was trying to push my codebase to other user repository on which i have permission, I got stuck with this error. It is not even helping me to change the remote origin. It is showing

> fatal: remote origin already exists

[image: error img]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [! \[rejected\] master -> master (fetch first)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28429819/rejected-master-master-fetch-first)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing changes from the remote branch master (other developers probably pushed to that branch already), that's why git is rejecting to accept your changes. Normally, you would pull (fetch and then merge or rebase) with your local branch and then you should be able to push normally.

Answer (score 1):

tell you fetch first so just try this

```
$ git push origin master --force
```

Or

```
$ git push origin master -f
```

it is same