# Can't push to remote repo

Tags: git, github

Okay. I used git clone to copy repo from GitHub to my local repo. I synchronized them. Then I added 2 new files to my local repo, then add -> commit to local repo.

Now i'm trying to push it to remote repo and got:

```
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:Rossamonaar/android_app_bot.git'
```

I read some topics and tried git pull. Git pull is ok, then git push origin master is also ok. Seems fixed? No! I pulled from remote repo and 2 files disappeared from my local repo. Kinda I'm in an endless circle.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [! \[rejected\] master -> master (fetch first)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28429819/rejected-master-master-fetch-first)

Comment: I suspect that you are trying to push to a repo which is owned by someone else and you don't have any association with it. I would suggest to fork it and raise a Pull request to get your changes merged.

Comment: There's a good chance @Raju is right