# Error when sending change to the cloud through Git

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to uploud my local project for the first time, when I do the `$git push` command the following error is returned:

```
fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

     git push --set-upstream origin master
```

After applying the tip the error is returned:

```
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '---------------' to the list of known hosts.
To github.com:LuisMatheus-dev/Gama-Academy.git
  ! [rejected] master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com: LuisMatheus-dev / Gama-Academy.git'

hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

How should I proceed ?

Comment: Does your network work? What does `git status` and `git log` say? What does the commit history on github look like. Why are you pushing master to master? Surely you should be pushing to origin/master? What command did you use for `git push`? In general please include lots of detail. Rarely can you provide too much detail

Comment: Also what have you tried? Have you googled your error message first?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve git error: "Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22532943/how-to-resolve-git-error-updates-were-rejected-because-the-tip-of-your-current)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Updates+were+rejected+because+the+tip+of+your+current+branch+is+behind

Comment: I edited the question for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remote master contains commits that your local master does not. Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28429887/13222971) helps.

Comment: I had seen this topic but I was in doubt as to *git fetch*. Would it overwrite changes to the local repository?
Because there is nothing in the github repository

Comment: If you really want to push to remote master then you can stash your local changes first with `git stash`, then execute `git pull` to not override your changes and the execute `git stash pop` to unstash your changes. `git fetch` does not override anything it fetches the most recent information from your remote.

Comment: 1) Run **$git stash**:
`Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: 64da888 Banner image`
2) **$git pull origin master**:
`From github.com:LuisMatheus-dev/Gama-Academy
  * branch master -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`

Comment: It seems like your local master and remote master are not really compatibel anymore.. Try the following. First, leave your changes stashed, then create a new branch `git checkout -b master-backup`, then delete your local master `git branch -D master`, then checkout the remote master `git checkout master`. Finally you can merge your master-backup to master and push it again.

Comment: Okay, but when I went to do the **$ git merge master-backup** it returns the error: 
`fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`

Comment: As suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37937984/git-refusing-to-merge-unrelated-histories-on-rebase `git merge --allow-unrelated-histories` should work...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212559/discussion-between-luis-matheus-and-michael-kreutz).