# ! [rejected] master -> master (fetch first) when pushing to git

Tags: django, github

Since the major change in policy- I used SSH key.
All went well until changes were made.

Now when I'm trying to push my changes this error pops :(

I pushed to 2 separate branches. I am the only dev on the project

`! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first) error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:kohenm63/phone_book.git' hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again. hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.`

Comment: Just run `git pull` before `git push`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [! \[rejected\] master -> master (fetch first)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28429819/rejected-master-master-fetch-first)

Comment: you commit the current changes, then pull the changes from the remote server, resolve the conflicts and push to the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

"This branch is 3 commits ahead, 3 commits behind main".

makes perfect sense to me.

did use the "force" =>git push origin master --force
but it only is commended when there's 1 person on the project which in my case applies...

Thank you all for your kind contribution!

Comment: git push origin master --force this works for me