# Subfolders do not show up on github

Tags: github, github-for-mac

I have pushed code to github however the subfolders do not have anything in them and they are greyed out on github. Is there a way to get the information inside the subfolder on github as well?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does a grey icon in remote GitHub mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19584255/what-does-a-grey-icon-in-remote-github-mean)

Answer (score 0):

Your post is a bit unclear on if the folders have any content in them. You say they do not have anything inside of them, but you also talk about the information inside subfolders.

If the folders are empty you can't add them, that's just how git works. If they have content, adding this content will make the folders show up as well.

Comment: The folders I am trying to add do have files inside of them. However, when I log in to github.com those files are greyed out and when I download as a zip the files show up as empty. When I added ran git add .

Comment: Are you sure they are empty? They might contain files hidden by your filesystem, like .DS_Store files on OSX. Maybe you can clarify your post by adding a screenshot, or a link to your github repo.

Comment: There is nothing in my src and images file

Comment: Looking at the repo it seems you made a submodule by creating a repo inside a repo. Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19584255/what-does-a-grey-icon-in-remote-github-mean)

Comment: I looked at the post however still no luck I redid everything again but still same issue

Comment: Is there a way to avoid creating a repo inside a repo. Right now my image file has png files inside of it and my src file has another folder with files within that

Comment: Create your main folder. Add your subfolder and files. Run `git init` on your main folder to make it into a repo and run `git add *`, again on your main folder, to add all of the files (including those in subfolders). Then use `git commit` and `git push` to store the files.

Comment: Finished that, but still same issue I must be doing something wrong

Comment: I did your steps then I created remote repo on github.com