# Removing subproject commit from github

Tags: git, github, git-commit, subproject

I have two repositories namely `A` and `B`. By mistake I cloned repo B inside A on my machine. I removed all the code from the repo B but when I pushed and merged my code from A on origin, it also shows a subproject commit `B` on Github repo.

I want to remove the subproject commit from my master on origin. Will these steps work?

`1. rmdir B (on my local repo A)
 2. Pushing my repo A to origin
 3. Merging`

Comment: Does it shows B as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/19585206/6309?

Comment: Yes. Exactly the same.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since GitHub displays B as a gray folder within A repo, that means B has been added to A as a submodule.
That gray folder is a **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)**, a [special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17442045/6309).

See "[How do I remove a Git submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162000/6309)":
Locally, do `git submodule deinit asubmodule` and `git rm B` (`B` without any trailing slash `B/`).
Then push to GitHub, and `B` should be gone.

Comment: But I already did rmdir B on my local 'A' repo. And after doing git diff, it shows that :
@@ -1 +0,0 @@
-Subproject commit hash_val

Comment: Did you also do a `git submodule deinit B`? Or at least a `git rm .gitmodules`? And then push `A` to `origin/A`.

Comment: No, none of these. I just did cd A/ and rmdir B.

Comment: @Hellboy my point is: `B` is declared as a submodule: you need to do some git commands to unregister `B` as a submodule or it will be displayed as such on GitHub. Specifically, you need to remove the gitlink (`git rm B`), and need to unregister it from the submodules list (`git submodule deinit B`). A simple system command like `rmdir` won't be enough to remove B as a submodule.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you want to remove commit which shown in diff like

```
-Subproject commit <old commit hash>
+Subproject commit <new commit hash>
```

go to submodule directory, than

```
git checkout <old commit hash>
```

return back to main project:

```
git add .
git commit --amend --no-edit
git push
```