# How to use git subtree with existing git sub repo?

Tags: git

I have a `parent_repo` and a `sub_repo` within it, like this:

```
.\parent
.\parent\parent_file.html
.\parent\.gitignore
.\parent\lib\sub_repo
.\parent\lib\sub_repo\sub_file.html
.\parent\lib\sub_repo\.gitignore
```

Before I know about `subtree` or `submodule`, I use git for both of the repos. But when people see the `parent_repo`, they cannot see the `sub_repo` 's code.

[image]

It is suggested that, I should use `subtree` or `submodule`. [What does a grey icon in remote GitHub mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19584255/what-does-a-grey-icon-in-remote-github-mean)

Then What should I do? To make the `sub_repo` code available in `parent_repo`?

---

I looked at the docs of submodule and subtree. It seems like subtree is better than submodule. But the tutorial are not very illustrative (https://medium.com/@v/git-subtrees-a-tutorial-6ff568381844#.aztjizd8g).

I run `git subtree add —-prefix=lib/sub_repo my-subtree master`, and it reports prefix `lib/sub_repo` already exists.

Is there any simpler example that I can follow?

Answer (score 3):

First let's explain what is the main difference between subtree and submodule:

both of them are used for having another repo inside existing repo. The main difference is that git `submodule` is independent self-contained repository while `subtree` store the date in the parent (original) repo.

---

### ***`Now let's dig in and explain in  more details:`***

> Is there any simpler example that I can follow?

***`Submodule`*** is a **standalone** git project so the code will be checked out to a **new folder** under the root folder and it's not part of your master branch.

Your root folder will contain a submodule file and you will have to `init && update` it on every clone you make.

```
# Add the desired submodule to your code base
git submodule add <url>
```

You must run two commands:

```
git submodule init
```

to initialize your local configuration file, and

```
git submodule update
```

to fetch all the data from that project and check out the appropriate commit listed in your superproject:

So the full script is this:

```
git submodule add <url>
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

You simply need to be in your root folder and then add the submodule folder.

```
git submodule add <url>
```

Now when you clone the project you simply need to init and update the submodule

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

Git 1.8.2 features a new option --remote

```
git submodule update --remote --merge
```

will fetch the latest changes from upstream in each submodule, merge them in, and check out the latest revision of the submodule.

[image]

---

## ***`git subtree`***

***Git subtree allows you to insert any repository as a sub-directory of another one***

Very similar to `submodule` but the main difference is where your code is managed. In submodules the content is placed inside a separate repo and is managed there which allow you to clone it to many other repos as well.

***`subtree`*** is managing the content as part of the root project and not in a separate project.

Instead of writing down how to set it up and to understand how to use it you can simply read this excellent post which will explain it all.

https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/05/the-power-of-git-subtree/

Comment: Thanks. I now deleted the repo, and then re-add it through `subtree`. Still experimenting with this feature.

Comment: But do the mapping in the subtree no longer works when the parent repo is cloned again and can't be used to pull in new updates or push upstream code changes back to the child or subtree repo, is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Thought I'd provide a more specific answer related to ***subtree*** approach. This was my preferred method because I needed to be able to push changes to the sub repo from the parent repo.

We just have to create the *parent* repo, remove the *existing* repo, then add the *existing* repo back to the *parent* repo as a **subtree**. Your local directory structure won't change and neither will any of your namespacing between modules.

Below assumes there is an *existing* repo on your local machine inside a folder *existing/* and you want to nest it inside a new *parent* repo in the folder *parent/*.

So the directory tree should look something like this:

```
parent/
 |
 +-- existing/
 |     |
 |     +-- .git/
 |     |
 |     ...
 ...
```

**Process**:

1. **!!! Commit any changes to the *existing* repo !!!** Otherwise, you will lose them.
2. Create new repo in *parent/* folder called *parent*

   - you’ll get a warning related to the nested *existing* repo; ignore it
3. Copy the *existing* folder to another location. You'll need it to copy back any files that are .gitignored
4. Remove the *existing/* folder with `rm -rf existing` and commit

   - Now any commits will be tracked in `parent` repo
5. Add the *existing* repo back as a subtree to *parent*:

   `git remote add existing https://github.com/username/existing.git`

   `git subtree add --prefix=existing/ existing master`
6. Copy back any files that were ignored and therefore not in the existing repo but necessary for your project

Thats it. Now you can push any changes to `existing` repo *separately* via `git subtree add`

Example:

In the folder *existing/*,

```
echo "a new text file in existing repo" >> newtextfile.txt
git add .
git commit -m "add new file to existing repo"
cd ../ # to parent folder
git subtree push --prefix=existing/ existing master
```

Remember changes to the *parent* repo also have to pushed separately and that changes to *existing* ***will be included in in the parent repo***.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but to help those who are facing the problem right now here's how to fix it, simply and without having to re-download the repo:

1. Rename the existing folder (eg. `subtree-dir` to `subtree-dir_temp`.

   ```
   mv original/subdir/path new/path/for/temp/dir`
   ```
2. Commit
3. Run Git Subtree `add` with the renamed folder as the remote.

   ```
   git subtree add --prefix=original/subdir/path path/to/renamed/folder master --squash
   ```

   As you can see we are entering the renamed folder path where the remote url would go, git doesn't care about this and is able to "pull" it.
4. Commit
5. Remove/delete the folder that was renamed as it has been already copied successfully by Git to the correct path.

   ```
   rm -r path/to/renamed/folder
   ```
6. Commit

The reason why you should commit in between changes is because Git creates commits automatically whenever a subtree is added, and therefore, it will complain if there are uncommited changes (for your own safety).