# Keep folders of two different repos in sync

Tags: git

Let say I have two repos `repo_A` and `repo_B`. Each gave number of folders. I want to keep one folder in `repo_A` in sync with `repo_B`.

E.g., Let say `repo_A` have folder - **x**  and `repo_B` have folder **y**. So these two repos always remain in sync.

Whenever I push to `repo_A` or `repo_B` and there is any change in any file or new file is added. The changes should also reflect i other repo too.

I don't know If it is possible or not So if it is even if with some exception or rules I have to follow please let me know

Comment: Check `git subtree` and `git submodule`.

Comment: @choroba they works for whole module or repo. But I want to sync folders only

Comment: I agree that subtree/submodule is the solution

Comment: Read this answer to fully understand what and how to use it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36720318/git-how-to-use-git-subtree-with-existing-git-sub-repo/36720642#36720642

Comment: Just create a repo for the folder.

Comment: @choroba yes able to solve my issue using 3rd repo but too complicated to setup