# How to clone the project to existing directory using sub tree

Tags: git, github

`git subtree add --prefix=projectpath https://github.com/newfivefour/vimrc.git master`

while i am trying to clone to the existing directory i am facing an error as 
prefix 'projectpath ' already exists.

Comment: You cannot `git subtree add` to an existing directory. If the directory `projectpath` is empty — remove it before using `git subtree add`. If it's not empty — choose a different name for the subtree.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git: How to use git subtree with existing git sub repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36720318/git-how-to-use-git-subtree-with-existing-git-sub-repo)