# I've cloned from another person's repository, now how do I push the code from my local computer to my own repository?

Tags: git, github

A couple of weeks ago I cloned a repository to my local computer. I added some code to some of the files. Recently, there were updates to the repository that I want to pull. However, I want to save my progress by pushing to my own repo, but when I do this I create submodules instead of actual folders in git. How can I save my progress before pulling from the updated repo?

Comment: you need to fork the repo to your github account then clone that repo to your local system and then you can push to that forked repo in your account, You won't be able to directly push to that user's repo, you have to make a pull request for that.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to add a git remote to your local copy and push there:

```
$ git remote add alexyang https://github.com/alexyang/myrepo
$ git push alexyang master
```

In this example `alexyang` is an arbitrary name that will be how you refer to the repository (analogous to "origin", essentially a nickname for the full repo url). `https://github.com/alexyang/myrepo` is the repo url. `master` could of course be replaced with whatever branch you want to push.

Once you've committed & pushed your changes to your repo, you can then `fetch` from the original repo:

```
$ git fetch origin
```

And merge in those changes, or continue how you see fit. You will now have 2 references to remote branches, probably named `origin/master` and `alexyang/master`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I added a git remote to my local copy, but when I add all the folders, commit, and push, my repository has only the submodules even though I expect to have folders. For example, if I had the folder named "cars" on my computer, after pushing, github shows that it is a submodule not a folder.

Comment: The only thing I can think is that empty folders are not tracked by git. You'd have to add an empty file (named anything, .gitkeep is common) to keep the folder.

What do you mean by submodule? Unless you have a .gitmodules file, it is unlikely that you actually have true git submodules happening in your repo. Is that the case?

Comment: Github shows two grey overlapping folder icons next to the name of my folder. I checked and I don't have a .gitmodules file.

Comment: Not entirely sure but check out this answer which might explain the meaning of the gray icon: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19584255/what-does-a-grey-icon-in-remote-github-mean