# Git treating directory like a file

Tags: git, bitbucket, linux-mint

I have an odd question, It seems as if Git is treating a directory as a file... Right after doing `git add .`:

[image]

Then, after my push, I get:
[image]

"mov" is actually a directory but it seems like it is being treated as a file when doing the git push, this even happens if I am inside the directory when doing the push. I have attenpted to add the file by going into the mov directory and running: git remote -v, however it didn't change anything.

Am I overlooking something? This has never happened to me before :(

Comment: Is mov also a Git repo? It looks like you've got a sub module.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does a grey icon in remote GitHub mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19584255/what-does-a-grey-icon-in-remote-github-mean)

Comment: The repo is: https://kevin192291@bitbucket.org/kevin192291/movgame.git You can clone it, and I am pretty sure you will not the the content of the mov directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mov` folder appears to have its own git repo and is therefor a submodule. Look for a `.git` folder inside of the `mov` folder. You can delete this directory to make `mov` part of the parent git repo.

Comment: Thank you... for some reason I am not seeing the .git file. I will go figure why that is now. I saw the .git file with: ls -al in terminal

Comment: @Kevin192291 In the Linux world, a file or directory that starts with . is hidden.  You can see them with `ls -a`.