# Pushed a subdirectory to Github, but the folder is grayed out with an icon I've never seen before. No access to the contents of the folder

Tags: git

I pushed a new subdirectory to a Github branch. However, on Github, the folder is grayed out with this icon which I've never seen before. [image: directory image]

I ran a `git status` and it says everything is up to date, and all the contents of the new directory are being tracked by git. How can I make this subdirectory accessible via github.com?

Comment: That icon is for an unreachable submodule: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19584255/what-does-a-grey-icon-in-remote-github-mean

Comment: @Dai ah okay thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does a grey icon in remote GitHub mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19584255/what-does-a-grey-icon-in-remote-github-mean)