# git clone Github repository with multiple submodules and git push

Tags: github

I need to clone a repository of a particular branch from github.com that has multiple submodules.
I am using git clone -b xxx --recurse-submodules http://github.com/reposname/repo.git
But when i am using git push to our internal github server it is greyed out the submodules folders.
I am using git push --prune https://internal.github.server/repo/repo.git
After cloning i am able to see all the submodules files in local repo. But while pushing it is getting greyed out.

Am i following the correct procedure of pushing the cloned repo(with submodules) to internal github server ?
Any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pushing submodule is nothing special.
You are pushing:

- the gitlinks (special entries in the index representing the submodule root tree SHA1)
- the .gitmodules file which stores the submodule remote URL

A [gray icon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19585206/6309) means the submodule destination is not publicly accessible, or references a SHA1 which is not publicly visible/pushed.

Comment: Great! What did you do?