# How to push Ionic app to GitHub

Tags: git, github, ionic-framework

First, I go into `GitHub` and click `Create Repository`, name the repository `KMtoMiles` and click create repository (I am not creating a read me or anything like that)

Then, I do these steps from the command line:

```
echo "# KMtoMiles" >> README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/Gl4di4torRr/KMtoMiles.git
git push -u origin master
```

So now the README.md file is pushed to my repo.

Now I do

```
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"
git push -u origin master
```

Now I have pushed all of my app onto GitHub.

However, when I go to GitHub, I see that my www directory is greyed out.

[image: GitHub directory]

So I am a `GitHub` noob. I have tried to do the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448601/what-does-this-green-icon-mean-in-a-github-repository)

But I can't get the whole `.gitmodule` thing or whatever to work for me. I have tried doing stuff like:

```
git submodule update --init
git submodule add <url> <directory>
```

But no luck.

I have also researched `Ionic's` documents for an intro to `GitHub` or something like that.

Comment: Why do you need a submodule ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you must create two repos: `KMtoMiles-root` and `KMtoMiles`.

The submodule to [`Gl4di4torRr/KMtoMiles`](https://github.com/Gl4di4torRr/KMtoMiles) is in your *other* repo [`Gl4di4torRr/KMtoMiles-root`](https://github.com/Gl4di4torRr/KMtoMiles-root).

That means a git clone --recursive https://github.com/Gl4di4torRr/KMtoMiles-root will:

- clone `KMtoMiles-root`
- and update `KMtoMiles-root/www` at the same time.

But on GitHub itself, that `www` folder will always remains gray and empty: it represents a pointer (a **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)**, [special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309), referencing a SHA1 of [`Gl4di4torRr/KMtoMiles`](https://github.com/Gl4di4torRr/KMtoMiles)).

**Ionic GitHub Example:**

For future reference on how to configure a submodule, you can use [this example](https://github.com/bouzuya/ionic-example-root) to configure your `.gitignore` and `.gitsubmodule`.