# Why github display gray folder to when I create a new repository?

Tags: git, github

Git command :

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "project"
git remote add origin https://github.com/
git push -u origin master
```

[Gray Folder github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qw5Im.png)

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: I'm not sure.  How does this affect you other than the color itself?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Directory showing up as a grey folder on github, but not tracking its content. Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35140715/directory-showing-up-as-a-grey-folder-on-github-but-not-tracking-its-content-w)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your repo includes a nested git repo (a subfolder with a `.git/` folder in it).

When you do a `git add .`, you will record that subfolder as a **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)** ([special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309)) which, once pushed to your GitHub repo, is displayed as a grayed folder.

See also "[Difference between nested git repos and submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34410102/6309)".

If you want to include that folder content into your sources, simply remove the `.git` folder of that gray directory, do a `git add .` again, commit and push.

Comment: @RaminFarajpourCami Great! Don't forget to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer and http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Comment: Ok ;) , Thanks Again