# Issue with remote GitHub repository

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, repository

Now, here is the format of the folder on my Linux machine:

```
/phd_simulations
    /ns-3
    /pybindgen
    /scenario
```

So ns-3, pybindgen, and scenario are all directories themselves...

Is this the correct workflow for git?  There is no Linux desktop client (yet), so bear with me:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "First commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/username/some-proj-name.git

git push
```

Right?

When I view the repository on GitHub.com, it only seems to be adding the folders themselves, NOT the contents.

I haven't used Git extensively yet (still learning), and I know I've done this successfully in the past, so I don't know what the deal is now.

Comment: What's the `git status`? Do you have a `.gitignore` file that might be interfering? Can you share the repo?

Answer (score 0):

It would add the folder only when those folders, locally on your computer, have a .git in them.
That would make them nested git repo, in which case, you should them as gray folder on GitHub.
See "[Why github display gray folder to when I create a new repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35334520/6309)"

If you want just their files, remove (or move) the .git out of the way, and re-init your repo (add, commit, `push --force`).
Make sure you don't need the history of those nested repo first.