# Folder not commited to github

Tags: github

I committed a folder to github and this is icon for given folder :

[image]

This is different to typical github folder :

[image]

Folder in first image appears empty but on local machine it contains approx 1000 sub-folders. Is this a pending state for given folder ?

I committed the folder approx 10 mins since posting this question.

Comment: Check out the following StackOverflow answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19584255/what-does-a-grey-icon-in-remote-github-mean http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448601/what-does-this-green-icon-mean-in-a-github-repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That usually happens when you have initialized git inside git.

Refer to [What does a grey icon in remote GitHub mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19584255/what-does-a-grey-icon-in-remote-github-mean)